# How do I stop Sketch from reseting the shape (reverting) after changing corner radius?

Tags: vector, path, sketch-app

When I change a shape's border radius after editing the vector points, it snaps back to the original shape. Any ideas?

[image: gif]

Comment: Seems the previous edit to this question made it too general. This appears to be a Sketch issue.

Comment: ups, i misread the tag "illustration" for "illustrator".

Comment: @boblet it was also tagged for Illustrator.. I removed that tag. The gif has absolutely no relation to Illustrator. So it may have simply been mis-tagged to start.

Comment: Ah, ok, i found it a little confusing, and there is the explanation. All is well; back to where it started. Weird problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try editing the radius of each point individually. You can do that by selecting a point and then choosing the Rounded point mode. You can read more about this here: http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/help/manual/vector-editing/using-the-vector-tool/

[image: Rounded corner]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a bug that you might be facing. I tried doing what you did and it worked fine.

There are however two ways to control radius, one is only on Primary Selection which only gives you overall radius control.

[image: Primary Selection]

And secondary Selection which allows you to control each point individually by selecting the required point.

[image: Secondary Selection]